# optimal SAT solver with weighted variables

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have $n$ boolean variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with associated real-valued costs $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, respectively, and a boolean function $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in conjunctive normal form (CNF). I'm looking for a dedicated (ideally free) software package to find an assignment for $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that satisfies $\Phi$ such that the total cost, that is, the sum of those $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ for which the respective $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are assigned a true value, is minimised.

My current solution is to convert the problem instance to a binary program and solve that with an implementation of the simplex algorithm + branch and cut (I'm using the GLPK package). I'm wondering whether there are software solutions better tailored for my kind of problem.

Comment: There are certainly faster integer programming codes than GLPK.  You should take a look at the academic codes CBC (open source) and SCIP (freely available for academics) and the commercial products CPLEX and Gurobi (also free for academics.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the [Weighted Partial MAX-SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem).  You could take a look at MAX-SAT solvers; many of them will support this kind of query.  For instance, the [annual MAX-SAT competition](http://www.maxsat.udl.cat/) has Weighted Partial MAX-SAT as one of the categories.  See [here](http://www.maxsat.udl.cat/16/results/index.html) for the results from the 2016 competition.  [MaxHS](http://www.maxhs.org/) looks quite good.

Alternatively, formulate this as an integer linear programming problem and then solve it with any off-the-shelf ILP solver: e.g., CPLEX, Gurobi, CBC, SCIP.